# C shift insert linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to insert at the beginning of the root of this function:

```c
struct elem { 
  int value;
  struct elem *next;
};

typedef struct elem Node;


void shiftInsert(Node *n, int v){
    int tmp;
    while (n != NULL){      


       n = n->next;
   }
}
```

When the `Node *n` is:
`1  -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5` and call `shiftInsert(88)`

the output of `Node *n` needs to be:

`88->1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`
 how can I achieve this?

Comment: Make a new `Node` and have it point to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `shiftInsert` is designed to insert a *value* at the beginning of the linked list, and then **push the first node's (former) value to the next node,** repeating until the last value has been "shifted" off. I would try something like:

```c
void shiftInsert(Node *n, int v) {

  Node *iterator = n;
  int tmpPrev = v;
  int tmpCurr = 0;

  while(iterator != NULL) {
    //save the current value
    tmpCurr = iterator->value;
    //set the new value
    iterator->value = tmpPrev;
    //save the old value
    tmpPrev = tmpCurr;
    //next node
    iterator = iterator->next;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/FaintNavajowhiteStrings)

Comment: Well, `v` needs to be the value of `n->value` and everything needs to shift to the right and the last value needs to be removed. So removing last element of `n` and adding `v` as first element like this: `1  -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5` becomes `88->1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4` when `v` is `88`

Comment: Ah, I was overcomplicating it. See edited answer.

Comment: Well, now the output is `88 ->  1 ->  2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 -> 10 -> NULL` which needs to be `88 ->  1 ->  2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 ->  9 -> NULL`

Comment: Off-by-one error! See final updated answer, and [demo](https://repl.it/repls/FaintNavajowhiteStrings).